# Remove ^H from gvim

Tags: gvim, formatting

I am trying to direct data from manpage to *gvim* file but it's not properly formatted.

Example:

- In manpage it is shown as **`NAME`** (bold)
- But in *gvim* its printed as `N^HNA^HAM^HME^HE`.
- Similarly for **`SYNTAX`** it prints `S^HSY^HYN^HNT^HTA^HAX^HX`.
- You can notice additional letter after(or before) `^H`.

Please suggest how to correct this.
Also suggest if there is any other way of re-directing, so that it keeps the formatting intact.

Comment: Unix and gvim are not file formats: one is an OS standard and the other an editor. Can you clarify (1) the exact steps you take to see the differences; (2) where the file comes from; and (3) what you mean by *direct data from unix to gvim*? I’ve seen similar things in man pages before for bolding effects.

Comment: Hello D.BenKnoble, sorry for not providing enough clarification. Your assumption is correct. This issue I am facing is of printing data of 'Manpage' to gvim editor, where it is creating formatting issue.

Comment: Shouldn't need an extra command. If you're using GNU tools then why not just `man --ascii`? (Other implementations should have some another way of dumping plain text if they don't have that flag. )  And, btw, you can't "preserve formatting" in any native way. Vim is a (plain) text editor.

Comment: @vikas try my answer using vim’s native man page environment.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are trying to capture the output from a program and open it on `gVim`... If that's the case, I'm afraid you will need to open the file with the output and then *remove* those `^H` and the repeated character that follows it.

```
%s/\v(.)^H\1/\1/g
```

Where:

`%s/` substitute in all lines:

`\v` uses *very magic mode* (see `:help /magic`)

`(.)^H\1` searchs for one character followed by `^H` and then by itself again (`a^Ha`, for example); note that in order to enter `^H` you need to press `^V` (or `^Q` if you were on a Windows machine) and then `^H`

`/\1/g` replace all the occurrences with the first character

PS: A long time ago, in order to print bold characters you would need to print it, than send a backspace and print it again; well, `^H` is that backspace character.

Comment: Indeed, the man and manpager plugin files that ship with vim do something similar

Comment: Hello João A. Toledo. Thanks a lot for your input. Your assumption is on point. 
 But command you provided is not working.  Error reported is "Pattern not found `\v(.)^H\1` ".

Comment: Good to know that you solved your problem in another way. Regarding the fact that it didn't find the pattern: maybe you didn't entered `^H` by pressing `Ctrl+V` and then `Ctrl+H`?

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP is dealing directly with manpages, I suggest

```
:runtime plugin/man.vim
```

(Which can be put in startup files), followed by

```
:Man command
```

Also see `help MANPAGER`

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

```
man <command> | col -b > <file>
```

This command dumps the file without `^H` and one extra character.
*Drawback*: bold letters are not bold, but at-least gvim file is now readable.

Answer (score 0):

if you use vim in mac could do following in command enter mode:

> Contrl + Q, Control + H

it will generate ^H in line.

Comment: Welcome to the forum! I think the OP is trying to prevent these characters to appear. How does this answer his question?

Comment: If OP cannot type ^H in command how to remove it, this is why I post. Type ^h in command and then use %s/^h//g to remove it all, few people know how to type special symbol in vim,  got it?

Comment: Oh, I get it now. So this is about the same as [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20272/22375), isn't it?

Comment: You might want to [edit] your answer to give the example of using it in a `:s` command to enter the `^H`. See also `:help c_CTRL-Q`. Also note that it's equivalent to `CTRL-V`, which I'd say is more standard for this purpose (personally I'd recommend using `CTRL-V` instead of `CTRL-Q`).

Comment: @Biggybi  why not try it in mac, `%s/\v(.)^H\1/\1/g` not work in mac. Instead, `:%s/^H//g` works fine.