# Windows save type breaks vim

Tags: microsoft-windows, encoding

So I wanted to use [this](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/msp-vim) plugin but if I start it, I'm getting this error message:
[image]

(I changed that line a bit to `hash('nvim')` but the `^M` still breaks the code because it has a the microsoft line-ending (as far as I know). Is it possible to make that file compatible for Windows and Linux?

Comment: `has` is the correct function name, no need to change that. We had another question with a similar issue recently, though I’m not sure if it was resolved

Comment: @D.BenKnoble do you mean this question? https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20268/remove-h-from-gvim

Comment: Found it. Be sure to check the comments too https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/28824/10604

Comment: Thank you very much! c(^-^)c

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer! I added those in my `init.vim`: `set ff=unix` and `set ffs=` (in this order). But it couldn't resolve my issue. Anyway, I don't need this plugin anymore. Should I/you create an answer so I can tick this as "answered"?

Comment: i dont have an “answer”—if you solved the problem, then an answer would be great. Otherwise unfortunately we should probably leave it open